# Python - A TypeError occurs calling a overwritten method

Tags: python

I'm running into a problem with method overwriting.

Look at the src code below,

```
class Foo(object):
  @staticmethod
  def bar():
    pass

Foo.bar() # works fine

print Foo.bar # <function bar at 0x028A5B30>

print dir(Foo.bar)
"""
['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__',
'__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__',
'__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
'__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 
'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
"""

backup = Foo.bar # keep the instance of the method object

Foo.bar = backup # overwrite with the same method object

print Foo.bar # <unbound method Foo.bar>

print dir(Foo.bar)
"""
['__call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
'__func__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', 
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', 
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'im_class', 'im_func', 'im_self']
"""

Foo.bar() # TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with Test instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

It is interesting that the Foo.bar.im_func attribute is actually the method and works just fine when invoked. I'm wondering if there's a way to recover the Foo.bar method with its im_func attribute? Please advice~

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to continue to be a static method then you must tell Python so when assigning. Otherwise it will become a normal method.

```
Foo.bar = staticmethod(backup)
```

Comment: The simple answer and solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you put a function as an attribute to an object, things get confusing: due to their `__get__()` methods, they behave differently than they appear. In order to understand that correctly, you should read [the section about data descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) in the Python docs.

A function as is has a `__get__()` method which will make the function appear as a method.

Suppose you have

```
def f(a): pass
class C(object):
    def m(a): pass # method
    sm = staticmethod(m)
    cm = classmethod(m)
o = C()
```

- `f` is then `<function f at 0xb742c87c>`, as is `C.__dict__['m']`.
- `f.__get__(None, object)` returns a method object `<unbound method object.f>`. If called, it checks if it is called with an instance of the given class, in this case `object`. This happens with an attribute access a class containing a function as a method, or with `C.m`, which is equivalent to `C.__dict__['m'].__get__(None, C)` and yields `<unbound method C.m>`.
- `f.__get__(4, object)` produces a `<bound method object.f of 4>`. which will call the original function bound to the object `4`, passing it as first parameter upon every call. This happens with an attribute access to an instance of the class. `o.m`, consequently, calls `C.__dict__['m'].__get__(o, C)` and yields `<bound method C.m of <__main__.C object at 0x...>>`.

In short:

```
>>> C.__dict__['m']
<function m at 0xb73bcd84>

>>> C.m
<unbound method C.m>
>>> C.m.im_class, C.m.im_self
(<class '__main__.C'>, None)
>>> C.__dict__['m'].__get__(None, C)
<unbound method C.m>

>>> o.m
<bound method C.m of <__main__.C object at 0xb73c64ac>>
>>> o.m.im_class, o.m.im_self
(<class '__main__.C'>, <__main__.C object at 0xb73c64ac>)
>>> C.__dict__['m'].__get__(o, C)
<bound method C.m of <__main__.C object at 0xb73c64ac>>
```

If you apply `staticmethod()` to a function and then assign it to an attribute in the class, you get similiar behaviour: a `staticmethod` object is an object whose `__get__()` does not produce a method object but the original function itself. See

```
>>> C.__dict__['sm']
<staticmethod object at 0xb73cd62c>

>>> C.sm
<function m at 0xb73bcd84>
>>> C.__dict__['sm'].__get__(None, C)
<function m at 0xb73bcd84>

>>> o.sm
<function m at 0xb73bcd84>
>>> C.__dict__['sm'].__get__(o, C)
<function m at 0xb73bcd84>
```

To be complete, here's how `classmethod()` works:

```
>>> C.__dict__['cm']
<classmethod object at 0xb73cd794>

>>> C.cm
<bound method type.m of <class '__main__.C'>>
>>> C.cm.im_class, C.cm.im_self
(<type 'type'>, <class '__main__.C'>)
>>> o.cm
<bound method type.m of <class '__main__.C'>>
>>> o.cm.im_class, o.cm.im_self
(<type 'type'>, <class '__main__.C'>)
>>> C.__dict__['cm'].__get__(type(C), C)
<bound method type.m of <class '__main__.C'>>
```

That said, you can see what happens in your case: first, you have a static method. But with

```
backup = Foo.bar
```

you get the original function, without `staticmethod` applied. On the way back,

```
Foo.bar = backup
```

, you assign the function to the attribute, making it an ordinary method of the class with the implications shown above, requiring to be called with a `Foo` instance (even if the function itself does not take any parameters, that is not the method object's business) and calling it automatically with another argument prepended to the others.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough explanation! I'm a newbie to Python. This definitely helps.:)

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like there's only 1 accepted answer within the thread...:(